# How to stop toggling of dynamic creating switch element

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

[image]

Hi, i am using checkbox as a switch and i am assiging dynmic id's to switch. But when i unckeck first checkbox then other checkbox checked checked and wiseversa

```
@forelse (\Auth::user()->dailyRemainders as $dailyRemainder)
                                
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
<div class="form-group col-sm-9">
<a href="{{route('delete.daily.remainder',['id' => $dailyRemainder>id])}}" 
class="delete-confirm">
<h6><input type="time" style="border: none; padding: 0;" value=" 
{{$dailyRemainder->time}}" readonly></h6>
<p style="color: #000000">{{$dailyRemainder->text}}</p>
</a>
</div>
                                    
<div class="col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_daily_remainder_notification" data-id=" 
{{$dailyRemainder->id}}" class="custom-control-input set_daily_remainder" 
id="customSwitch{{$dailyRemainder->id}}333" {{($dailyRemainder- 
>is_day_planner_notification) ? 'checked' : ''}}>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch{{$dailyRemainder- 
>id}}333"></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
@empty
@endforelse
```

In above code switch created dynamic and id's also different for all switch
and Ajax code is

```
$('.set_daily_remainder').on('change', function(){
        
        let id = $(this).data('id')
        let set_daily_remainder;
        
        if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
            set_daily_remainder = 1;
        }else{
            set_daily_remainder = 0;
        }
    
        $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('update.setdailyremainder.status')}}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "set_daily_remainder": set_daily_remainder,
            "id": id,
        },
        success: function(result){
        jQuery.each(result.errors, function(key, value){
                jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                jQuery('.alert-danger').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
            });
            // location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    });
```

How can i slove this.

Comment: Please show enough relevant code to demonstrate the problem as per [mcve]

Comment: I have update my code kindly check it

Comment: Nothing shown would cause another checkbox to change

Comment: Thanks for your response it was name issue because these element create dynamically and all checkbox contain same name. so i removed name it solved my issue